# Cannot find module in path defined in tsconfig

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

This drives me crazy, I am missing something but I can not figure out what it is.

Given the following imports:

```
import { SOME_SCHEMA } from '../../../schema/src/schemas/someschema';
import { SomeType } from '../../../someComponent/src/types/someType';
```

I want to shorten the path by adding alias to the `tsconfig` like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "schema/*": ["../schema/src/*"],
      "someComponent/*": ["../someComponent/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

and then I import them like this:

```
import { SOME_SCHEMA } from 'schema/schemas/clientTaskSchema';
import { SomeType } from 'someComponent/types/someType';
```

My IDE does not complain and can find both definitions. However when I build I get an error only for `SomeType` (but not for `SOME_SCHEMA`.

Cannot find module 'someComponent/types/someType' or its corresponding type declarations.

17 import { SomeType } from 'someComponent/types/someType';

Answer (score 2):

From the official typescript documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths):

> Note that this feature does not change how import paths are emitted by tsc, so paths should only be used to inform TypeScript that another tool has this mapping and will use it at runtime or when bundling.

With that said, I would suggest using a tool like [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) to load modules whose location is specified in the paths section of tsconfig.json, at runtime.

So that instead of running `tsc` to compile typescript into javascript, you'd have this instead:

```bash
tsc && node -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/${yourStartScript}.js
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I wonder why one works while the other doesn't

Comment: I might need to see the folder structure to be able to make an informed guess, if you don't mind :)

Comment: I will try to provide more information. However both "components" (schema and someComponent) have different webpack.configs maybe that is something to look into

Comment: the hint with the folder structure was helping me ;)

Comment: That’s great to hear!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue for me was as follows:

I had to add the `"someComponent/*": ["../someComponent/src/*"]` to the `someComponent` tsconfig as well because some parts of the code in `someComponent` was referencing files from the current component which imported `someType` from `someComponent` and since the path was not in the `tsconfig` of `someComponent` it was not found.